# How to show the number of participants in the last sent/taken quiz?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a simple Quiz Engine similar to that one in the ASP.NET website. I have the following database design:

> User Table: Username, Name, DivisionCode... etc
>
> Division Table: SapCode, Division
>
> Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, IsSent, Description
>
> UserQuiz: UserQuizID, QuizID, DateTimeComplete, Score, Username

Every week, the employees in my company will recieve an email notification to participate in the new quiz that is avaliable in the system. The quiz that will be sent to the employees will have (True) as a value of IsSent attribute and this is what discriminates it from the other quizzes which are not being sent to the employees. What I want now is showing the number of participants in the last taken quiz since there is only one quiz will be sent each week.

My Query that shows the total number of participants in all taken quizzes:

```
SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Number of Participants], dbo.Quiz.QuizID
FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID
WHERE     (dbo.Quiz.IsSent = 1)
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.Quiz.QuizID
```

**So how to fix it to show only the number of participants in the last taken quiz (the quiz that is sent)?**

Comment: It should show the result for the last one only not all of the quizzes that are sent to the employees

Comment: How do you determine what "the last one" is? You don't have a table datetime field :s

Comment: Can we determine that by the QuizID and IsSent values?

Comment: Only if it is an incremental value. You didn't mention if it was or not.

Comment: It is an incremental, so how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Rank all the `IsSent = 1` quizzes in the descending order of `QuizID`, then pick the second ranked:

```
;
WITH SentQuizRanked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QuizID DESC) AS rnk
  FROM dbo.Quiz
  WHERE IsSent = 1
)
SELECT
  d.DivisionShortcut,
  COUNT(DISTINCT uq.Username) AS [Number of Participants],
  q.QuizID
FROM dbo.Divisions d
  INNER JOIN dbo.Employee  e ON d.SapCode  = e.DivisionCode
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserQuiz uq ON e.Username = uq.Username
  INNER JOIN dbo.Quiz      q ON uq.QuizID  = q.QuizID
WHERE q.rnk = 2  /* the #1 quiz is the one being advertised,
                    so #2 is the last one taken */
GROUP BY
  d.DivisionShortcut,
  q.QuizID
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I got the following error and I don't know why: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'ROW_NUMBER'.

Comment: @AliAhmed: Missed a comma between `*` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, sorry.